# Ein vs Eine vs Einen.

Tags: english-to-german, german-to-english

I am very new to German. As I am learning it by myself I get confused very often among the following:

When to use:
-> **Ein vs Eine vs Einen ?**
Background: I kind of know its more or less related to gender but I have seen myself getting confused with my logic around this.

-> **Das vs Die vs Der ?**

similarly

**-> Hast vs Habt vs Hat?**

Could someone please explain me these with basic examples?

Comment: This question (actually three questions) covers so many topics (case, gender, verb conjugation) that an answer would become an introduction into German grammar, and that is not the purpose of German Language SE. Please read a good introduction into German grammar and ask here if you have a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

To (partially) answer just your first question (please ask only one question at a time): The word *ein* varies with gender (as you said) and also with case. You should look at a [table](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ein#Artikel) that lists the forms and learn about grammatical case in German.